# Could multiple sentient humanoids live in the same environment?

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process

In my Fantasy Story there's multiple fantasy species which have achieved human intelligence and many share a close common ancestry with humans (humans also live in the same lands). But I have realized that many real-life human relatives (neanderthals) have gone extinct. So would it be unrealistic (or even possible) for multiple intelligent humanoids to live with each other on the same continent with each other? Without the risk outcompeting or even interbreeding each other to extinction? Or just flat out killing and hunting other races to extinction?

Comment: see if these are helpful. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/206606/how-can-humans-survive-in-an-ecosystem-that-includes-longer-lived-elves/206612#206612 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/209946/could-a-single-species-be-arbitrarily-diverse/209978#209978 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176980/how-would-dozens-of-humanoid-species-affect-early-migrations/176993#176993

Comment: The neanderthal were not "human relatives". They were real humans. Yes, they look a bit different from other humans, but that did not stop them from having children together. Just like in Latin America most people are of mixed descent. "Without interbreeding" is not what humans do.

Comment: The Neanderthals didn’t go extinct; they were simply absorbed by the Cro-Magnons, as were the Denisovans. And there’s your problem: if your “species” are related closely enough to be interfertile, they’re really just one big species. You must physically separate them for millions of years for the genomes to diverge enough to matter.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your definition of "Same Environment" and "Live [together]."

I assume Europe vs North Americas wouldn't qualify, but what about many other real world analogs?

Japan was a fairly isolated nation until the 16th century though it interacted with China. Most of Africa remained fairly untouched by the Western world even if they were neighbors with those that did interact with them. You'll find it pretty difficult for cultural diffusion / genetic mix to affect these regions at any fundamental level.

Now I realize you were talking more along the lines of relatively more genetically distinct species like Neanderthal / Homo Sapiens etc. but in what way do they fail to meet your criteria of "having lived in the same environment"? Because anthropologists determined they interbred and eventually their share the same children? How does that invalidate the fact they coexisted for tens of thousands of years if not more prior to that point? Does your world span over evolutionary time scales?

Comment: Nice answer ! +1, agree, there's actually no reason to always assume hostility... peoples, *also* intelligent, late stone age peoples, could trade, interbreed, or remain completely isolated, for many 1000s of years.

Comment: I guess I should've been more specific, what I mean by 'same environment' or 'living together' is the groups interact with each other on a more regular basis. Like it wouldn't be rare for them to see each other, talk to each other, or even live in the same city. They would fail to meet my criteria if they never interact. I should've just said if they interact with each other.

Comment: I think there may be some level of misconception on the way anthropology works. I would suggest taking a look into the Magyar peoples and how Hungarians changed from Asiatic appearances to more European in appearance. While you're at it, look into English Melting Pot. It's pretty fascinating and I'm personally interested in seeing how Brazil as we know it today will turn out in the future. None of these happen within a couple generations, so unless time in your world happens at faster than evolutionary timescales it should be a non-issue.